# How to link a video capture and a frame-by-frame analysis ( in .jpg )?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I'm trying to make a Python program using OpenCV, which could both capture a video from the webcam, and analyse its pictures. So, the program is in two parts.
The video capture, which works correctly :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

   _, frame = cap0.read()
   hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   lower_beige = np.array([90,00,40])
   upper_beige = np.array([150,255,135])
   mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_beige, upper_beige)
   res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)
```

And the image analysis :

```
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
image, contours, hierarchy = 
cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cnt = contours[0]
area=cv2.contourArea(cnt)
perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
img = cv2.drawContours(img, hull, -1, (0,0,255), 3)
area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
print(area)
```

What I wanted to do is to use each 'mask' variable, which is a frame of the video ( although a bit modified ), and analyse it in real time, for example with : "img = cv2.imread(mask,-1)" bewteen the two programs, in order to link them. However, since 'mask' is a frame of the video, and 'img' HAS TO be a .jpg picture, how could I manage to link the programs ?
Thank you

Comment: I don't understand this question. JPEG is a compression method for storing images. When you read a JPEG image to `Mat`, it's data is decompressed and stored in `Mat`, just like when you read a video file frame by frame.

Comment: I don't really know how to solve it, so sorry if I was unclear in my explainations. The problem is that "img = cv2.imread(mask,-1)" doesn't work, since imread requires 'mask' to be .jpg whereas it isn't. However, what is 'Mat' ?

Comment: you dont have to do a cv2.imread(mask) when you already have the mask. If its in a different function that you are using it from/in, you should declare it as global variable for linking. Inorder to use imread for what you are doing, you first need to write the mask with cv2.imwrite().
Adding your full code might get you more help.

Comment: Hello, sorry I was stuck with a few other problems I managed to solve, and now I am back here again.
I didn't think about 'imwrite' at first, but indeed you're probably right.
I tried to use 

img = cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY('D:\(path)', mask)

But now, I get the error :
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

What does it mean ? Thanks